# How to calculate the phase difference between current and voltage?

Tags: circuit-analysis, power-electronics, fourier

Using the next circuit and the components of

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXwBeQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- \$R=20\Omega\$
- \$L=25mH\$
- \$V_{DC}=36\$
- \$v_{s}(t)=50+\underset{n=1}{\overset{\infty}{\Sigma}}(\frac{400}{n\pi})sin(200n\pi t)\$

The idea is determinate the average power absorbed by R.

So using the Fourier series based on the generalized Parseval identity
\$\frac{1}{L}\int_{0}^{c+2L}f(x)g(x)dx=\frac{a_{0}c_{0}}{2}+\overset{\infty}{\underset{n=1}{\Sigma}}(a_{n}c_{n}+b_{n}d_{n})\$

\$P=V_{o}I_{0}+\underset{n=1}{\overset{\infty}{\Sigma}}\frac{V_{m}I_{m}}{2}cos(\theta_{n}-\phi_{n})\$

\$I_{0}=\frac{V_{0}-V_{DC}}{R}=\frac{50-36}{30}=0.7\,A\$

\$P_{0R}=(0.7^{2})(20)=9.8\$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
n & V & I & Z & Angle & P\\ \hline 
\hline 
\hline 
0 & 50 & 0.7 & 20 & 0 &9.8\\ \hline
\hline 
1 &\frac{400}{\pi}=127.32 & \frac{V}{Z}=5.00 & \sqrt{20^{2}+(200\pi25mH)^{2}}=25.43 &  & \\ \hline
\hline 
2 &\frac{400}{2\pi}=63.66 & 1.7& 37.24 &  & \\ \hline
\hline 
3 & \frac{400}{3\pi}=42.44 & 0.829 & 51.19 &  & \\ \hline
\hline 
4 & \frac{400}{4\pi}=31.83 & 0.4827 & 65.93&  & \\ \hline
\hline 
5 & \frac{400}{5\pi}=25.46 & 0.3141& 81.04 &  &  \\ \hline
\hline 
\end{array}

But where Im stuck is how can be calculated the phase difference (the angle column) between the current and the voltage, since I think the second angle of \$cos(\theta_{n}-\phi_{n})\$ would be zero for every term of the series.

**UPDATE**
Whith the idea of The Photon that the inductor current indeed is out of phase but this can't cause the resistor voltage and current to be out of phasem and using the RL impedance

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
n & V & I & Z & Angle & P\\ \hline 
\hline 
\hline 
0 & 50 & 0.7 & 20 & 0 &9.8\\ \hline
\hline 
1 &\frac{400}{\pi}=127.32 & \frac{V}{Z}=5.00 & \sqrt{20^{2}+(200\pi25mH)^{2}}=25.43 & 0.665 & 250.47 \\ \hline
\hline 
2 &\frac{400}{2\pi}=63.66 & 1.7& 37.24 & 1.003  & 29.099\\ \hline
\hline 
3 & \frac{400}{3\pi}=42.44 & 0.829 & 51.19 &  1.169& 6.879\\ \hline
\hline 
4 & \frac{400}{4\pi}=31.83 & 0.4827 & 65.93& 1.262 &2.334 \\ \hline
\hline 
5 & \frac{400}{5\pi}=25.46 & 0.3141& 81.04 & 1.321 &0.988  \\ \hline
\hline 
\end{array}

So the average power absorbed by R is \$299.57 W\approx300 W\$

Comment: There won't be any phase difference between the voltage across and current through the resistor. But if you were to calculate the current sourced by the ac source, you would find a phase difference relative to its voltage.

Comment: Why use Fourier series?

Comment: @Chu, because I dont know if there is another way to do it.

Comment: @ThePhoton, thats what puzzle me, because of the inductor there would be necessarily a shift delaying the phase

Comment: The current through the inductor is out of phase with the voltage across it. That doesn't (can't) cause the resistor voltage and current to be out of phase.

Comment: @ThePhoton, Great idea, that's why this was not fitting at all.

Comment: @riccs_0x Your final answer is wrong. Look at my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

- You can use the impedance of the R-L combination to find the current through the circuit due to each Fourier component.
- You can then use Ohm's law to get the voltage across the resistor due to each Fourier component.
- Then you can use the formula for power (derived from [Parseval's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem)) as stated in your post to get the power.

One more hint:

- Since the inductor, on average, consumes no power, the average power dissipated by the resistor is equal to the average power delivered by the sources in this circuit. So after you've found the circuit current, you might rather just calculate the source power than the resistor power.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from the Laplace domain, the voltage across the resistor is given by:
$$V_R(s)=\frac{1}{sL+R}V_{in}(s) \Rightarrow \frac{V_R(s)}{V_{in}(s)}=\frac{1}
{sL+R} = H(s)$$ It can be seen that, as expected, the RL circuit is a stable linear system, since the (real) pole is in the left half plane.

Converting to the Fourier domain by substituting \$s=j\omega\$ (since we are only interested in the steady state response):
$$\Rightarrow H(j\omega)=\frac{1}{j\omega{L}+R}$$

Since \$H(j\omega)\$ represents the transfer function of a stable linear system, the response to a general input \$x(t)=A\cos(\omega {t} + \phi)\$ is given by:

$$y(t)=A\vert H(j\omega)\vert \cos[\omega {t} + \phi + \angle{H(j\omega)}]$$

Therefore, for an input voltage given by 
$$v_{in}(t)=86+\frac{400}{\pi}\cdot\sum_{\text{n}=1}^\infty\frac{\sin\left(200\pi\cdot\text{n}\cdot t\right)}{\text{n}}$$
and using the superposition principle, the voltage across the resistor is given by:
$$v_R(t)=86 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty {\frac{400}{n\pi} \frac{R}{\sqrt{R^2+\omega_n^2 L^2}} \sin \Big[200\pi {n} {t} - \tan^{-1}\left( \frac{\omega_n L}{R} \right)  \Big]}$$
where $$\vert H(j\omega)\vert = \frac{R}{\sqrt{R^2+\omega_n^2 L^2}}$$

Now, since the voltage and current across a resistor are in phase, the current through the resistor is $$i_R(t)= \frac{86}{R} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty {\frac{400}{n\pi} \frac{1}{\sqrt{R^2+\omega_n^2 L^2}} \sin \Big[200\pi {n} {t} - \tan^{-1}\left( \frac{\omega_n L}{R} \right)  \Big]}$$

The instantaneous power dissipated by the resistor is:
$$p(t)=i_R(t)\cdot v_R(t)$$
The average power dissipated by the resistor is $$ \Rightarrow P_{avg}=\frac{1}{T}\int_0^T{i_R(t)\cdot v_R(t)}\mathrm{d}t=\frac{1}{T}\int_0^T{\frac{v_R^2(t)}{R}}\mathrm{d}t = \frac{1}{R}\Big[ \frac{1}{T}\int_0^T{v_R^2(t)}\mathrm{d}t \Big]=\frac{V_{RMS}^2}{R}$$

Finally (with some careful algebra):
$$V_{RMS}^2= 86^2 + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty {\left(\frac{400}{n\pi} \frac{R}{\sqrt{R^2+\omega_n^2 L^2}}\right)^2} $$

Substituting \$R=20\Omega\$, \$L=25m\mathrm{H}\$ and \$\omega_n = 200\pi {n}\$, gives the average power as:
$$P_{avg} = \frac{V_{RMS}^2}{R} = \frac{86^2}{20} +\frac{1}{2}{\frac{1}{20}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{400}{n\pi} \frac{20}{\sqrt{20^2+{200^2\pi^2 {n^2}} \times \left(25\times 10^{-3}\right)^2}}\right)^2} $$
Simplifying gives:
$$P_{avg} = \frac{1849}{5} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty {10\left( \frac{400}{n\pi \sqrt{400 + 25\pi^2 n^2} }  \right)^2}=\frac{17422}{15}-500\coth\left(4\right) \approx 661.131W$$